# Set ratio of Columns in mat-grid

Tags: html, css, angular-material

How can I set width of cols in mat-grid.
This is my sample [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fj8zfr?file=app/grid-list-overview-example.html). I want to set the ratio of first column to 30% and the other to 70%.
In CSS Grid we can do this way up:

```
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 0.6fr 1.4fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr;
grid-template-areas: "\31  \32 ";
}

.\31  { grid-area: \31 ; }
.\32  { grid-area: \32 ; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding col-span did the trick.
Make sure that the sum of col span is equal to cols Size.

```
 <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="2:1" >
 <mat-grid-tile colspan="3">1</mat-grid-tile>
 <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">2</mat-grid-tile>
 </mat-grid-list>
```

Working [Stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fj8zfr?file=app/grid-list-overview-example.html)

If you remove the col span then both columns will be of 50% ratio.
Similarly you can set row span as well.